# Django url not hitting the right endpoint

Tags: python, django, regex, django-rest-framework

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse 

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView

from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


class ActivateUser(GenericAPIView):

    def get(self, request, uid, token, format = None):
        payload = {'uid': uid, 'token': token}

        url = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/users/activation/"
        response = requests.post(url, data = payload)

        if response.status_code == 204:
            return Response({}, response.status_code)
        else:
            return Response(response.json())
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('account.urls')),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uid>[\w-]+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/$', views.ActivateUser.as_view())
]
```

error:

> Page not found (404)
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000//activate/MjU/brgs37-d7dee487798f432dc9fb24478dae100b
>
> Using the URLconf defined in artist_portal.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/
>
> api/
>
> [name='index']
>
> ^activate/(?P[\w-]+)/(?P[\w-]+)/$
>
> The current path, /activate/MjU/brgs37-d7dee487798f432dc9fb24478dae100b, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: In the request url you provided, there is a double slash ('//') after port 8000. Remove one slash & try.
 Correction: http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/MjU/brgs37-d7dee487798f432dc9fb24478dae100b

Comment: even with a double slash this code works and hits the proper url for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your urls.py file, you have defined the activation URL pattern as:

```
re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uid>[\w-]+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/$', views.ActivateUser.as_view())
```

However, when the URL is requested, it includes a double slash (//) before the activate part:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000//activate/MjU/brgs37-d7dee487798f432dc9fb24478dae100b
```

To fix this issue, you can modify the URL pattern by removing the leading slash. Update your urls.py file as follows:

```
re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uid>[\w-]+)/(?P<token>[\w-]+)/$', views.ActivateUser.as_view())
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Hi, Kiarash Gh!  Your answers today appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.